# Somatoria acumulando colunas em uma matrix no R

Tags: r, apply, matriz

Eu tenho a seguinte situação :

Em uma matrix numerica tipo :

```
Temp <- matrix(runif(25, 10, 100),nrow=5,ncol=5)

V1    V2    V3    V4    V5

11    34    45    54    55
16    21    45    75    61
88    49    85    21    22
12    13    12    11    10
69    45    75    78    89
```

Como transformar essa matrix em uma matrix que seja a somatoria acumulada das colunas ? O resultado seria o seguinte

```
V1    V2    V3    V4    V5

11    45    90    144   199
16    37    82    157   218
88    137   222   243   265
12    25    37    48    58
69    114   189   267   356
```

Eu consegui o objetivo usando um for loop, mas acredito que deva existir uma maneira mais eficiente de fazer uma vez que estou trabalhando com uma matrix de 2580 linhas por 253 colunas e esta demorando um pouco para gerar o resultado

```
Temp <- matrix(runif(25, 10, 100),nrow=5,ncol=5)
Temp <- round(Temp,0)
sum_matrix <- matrix(0,nrow=nrow(Temp),ncol=ncol(Temp))
sum_matrix[,1] <- Temp[,1]
    for (n in 2:nrow(Temp)) {
        sum_matrix[,n] <- sum_matrix[,n-1] + Temp[,n]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `cumsum` para obter a ***cum***ulative ***sum*** dos elementos da sua matrix. E o `apply`, somado ao `t` (transpose) pode ser usado para obter o resultado que você precisa:

```
temp <- t(matrix(c(11, 34, 45, 54, 55,
                   16, 21, 45, 75, 61,
                   88, 49, 85, 21, 22,
                   12, 13, 12, 11, 10,
                   69, 45, 75, 78, 89)
    ,nrow=5,ncol=5))
temp2 <- t(apply(temp, 1, cumsum))
temp2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   11   45   90  144  199
[2,]   16   37   82  157  218
[3,]   88  137  222  243  265
[4,]   12   25   37   48   58
[5,]   69  114  189  267  356
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma usando os pacotes `dplyr` e `tidyr` seria a seguinte:

```
> library(tidyr)
> library(dplyr)
> 
> temp <- matrix(1:25, 5, 5)
> temp <- data.frame(id = 1:5, temp)
> temp
  id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  1  6 11 16 21
2  2  2  7 12 17 22
3  3  3  8 13 18 23
4  4  4  9 14 19 24
5  5  5 10 15 20 25
> temp %>%
+   gather(variavel, valor, -id) %>%
+   group_by(id) %>%
+   arrange(variavel) %>%
+   mutate(valor = cumsum(valor)) %>%
+   spread(variavel, valor)
Source: local data frame [5 x 6]

     id    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
  (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
1     1     1     7    18    34    55
2     2     2     9    21    38    60
3     3     3    11    24    42    65
4     4     4    13    27    46    70
5     5     5    15    30    50    75
```

Para usar esse formato, seus dados devem estar armazenados em um data.frame.

Note que se esse tipo de manipulação faz sentido no seu banco de dados quer dizer que ele não está no formato tidy. Para entender mais o porque do formato tidy ser ideal para usar no R, vale muito a pena [ler esse artigo do Hadley](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10).